# Kali dual boot, Can't boot into Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kali-linux, grub

I have installed Kali 2017 everything went fine installation finished. After restart GRUB loader don't shows any option to load into Windows only option to load into Kali. 
I have read somewhere to manually edit grub file like below but after this selecting windows option in grub shows error `disk 'hd0,msdos4' not found`.

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos4)'
chainloader +1
}
```

[image]

Last three partitions are created after installing kali.
Also in boot menu in efi only kali grub is showing as boot device. 
I have tried sudo update-grub too but no success.

update GRUB

[image]

There is no windows boot manager in the boot menu there is only option for Kali, have i did something wrong.

Comment: Is the package `os-prober` installed? If not install it. And do show the output of `update-grub`

Comment: its kali, unable to found os-prober @Hunter.S.Thompson

Answer (score 1):

You need `os-prober` to detect your windows.

```
apt-get install os-prober
update-grub
```

Comment: actually i think i have removed the partition which contains boot information of windows. Any way i can repair that ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as boot information of windows. If you are able to enter Kali from grub, your boot information is intact. Did you try my answer?

Comment: I tried but does't help.